# Recursive string parsing into object

Tags: javascript, parsing, recursion

Hello guys I'm trying to parse an array of strings into a custom structure:

```
var str = [
"country.UK.level.1",
"country.UK.level.2",
"country.US.level.1",
"country.UK.level.3"
];
```

Into something like:

```
var ordered = {
   "country": [
      {"UK" : {"level" : ["1", "2", "3"]}},
      {"US" : {"level" : ["1","2"]}}
   ]
}
```

Notes:

- Strings stored in the `str` array will not be sorted and the code should be robust against that.
- Strings will follow the `x.y.x.y...` pattern, where `x` will be unique for that array and `y` can change. In my example `country` and `level` will always be the same as they represent the `x` pos.
- This requires recursive approach as the strings stored in the `str` array, can be of any length. The longer the string the deeper nesting.

Comment: JSON (JavaScriptObjectNotation) is JavaScript. But JavaScript is not JSON.

Comment: @DavidVollmers Neither is the other. There are similarities, but one is a scripting language and the other is a data serialisation format.

Comment: I welcome your critique, I'm not an expert at this, and if you find something is not accurate, it would be nice if you've edited my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you if the last level of your object is an array:

```
var str = [
"country.UK.level.1",
"country.UK.level.2",
"country.US.level.1",
"country.UK.level.3"
];

var obj = {};

str.forEach(function(str){
    var curr = obj;
    var splitted = str.split('.');
    var last = splitted.pop();
    var beforeLast = splitted.pop();

    splitted.forEach(function(sub){
        if(!curr.hasOwnProperty(sub))
        {
            curr[sub] = {};
        }

        curr = curr[sub];
    });

    if(!curr[beforeLast]){
        curr[beforeLast] = [];
    }
    curr[beforeLast].push(last);
})

console.log(obj);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jsq0xqu1/).

Comment: forEach call requires IE9+

Comment: @px5x2 - And? Whats the problem with that? The OP said nothing about IE < 9. And re-writing the code without a forEach will take about 30 seconds.

Comment: From reading Eloquent JavaScript I learnt that forEach is much slower than an old-school for loop, with deep nesting as well.

Comment: @AmirPopovich nothing wrong, just wanted to state. Like we all write code completely unaware of browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

This solution utilized a `Array.prototype.forEach` and `Array.prototype.reduce`.

```js
var str = [
        "country.UK.level.1",
        "country.UK.level.2",
        "country.US.level.1",
        "country.UK.level.3"
    ],
    ordered = {};

str.forEach(function (a) {
    var aa = a.split('.'),
        val = aa.pop(),
        last = aa.length - 1;

    aa.reduce(function (obj, pro, i) {
        if (!(pro in obj)) {
            obj[pro] = i === last ? [] : {};
        }
        return obj[pro];
    }, ordered).push(val);
});
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(ordered, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```